# Connecting to https service in java -- hostname has "_" in it?

Tags: java, android, wcf, azure

I want to connect to a wcf json service hosted on windows azure with https (webHttpBinding with transport security). The address is some_subdomain.somesite.com, which of course redirects to someapp.cloudapp.net
I can't use "some_subdomain.somesite.com" because of the "_" in the hostname.

The original code

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serviceUrl + "/" + serviceMethod);
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
String jsonParameters = gson.toJson(parameters);
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonParameters));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); // throws here
return convertStreamToString(entity);
```

throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null;

This similar code:

```
        InputStream inputStream;            
        URL url = new URL(serviceUrl + "/" + serviceMethod);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect(); // throws exception here
        if(httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            ...
        }
```

throws a NullPointerException.

If I just put in the IP, then I get

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: IP_ADDRESS != some_subdomain.somesite.com

I'm using a production certificate, so changing the domain and getting another certificate might not be an option.
Note that everything works ok on the iOS and WinRT versions, only java seems to have a problem with the hostname.

So how can I:
a) use an URL with "_" in the hostname OR
b) configure the expected identity of the server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put underscores in the hostname, see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) and [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952).